# Multiline Read in Java Console does not quit

Tags: java, console

I am using following code to do a multiline read in Java. The issue is, since the console is running, it never exits the while loop. How can I make it do that?

Thanks

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String temp = scanner.nextLine();
        data.add(temp);
        log.info(data.toString());
    }
    scanner.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.in` will always have a next line from the point of view of the Scanner, because it is always waiting for new input. If you've got no blank lines within your input, you could just add a blank line to the input at the end, and then add this at the end of the loop:

```
if(temp.isEmpty()){
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

linux shell: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> (end-of-file)

windoze: get linux (or gitbash)

Answer (score 0):

You don't read from a file with the *Scanner* class, you're reading from the default input stream, which doesn't have an EOF (End of file) character. The problem with this: The *hasNextLine()* method doesn't recognize that there is no more input! Try something like this to read from command line:

```
String temp;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

while((temp = scanner.nextLine()) != null)
{
  data.add(temp);
  log.info(data.toString());
  ...
}

scanner.close();
```

To exit the loop manually, use the options of [user2023577](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2023577/user2023577)...